# Sign XML doc in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Does anybody know how to sign a XML document.
It is very easy to do that in .net platform because there are built in libraries that do it for you. It is just a few rows of code.
Firstly, I need to normalize (canonize) the XML doc and then sign it.
I need something like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229745.aspx
Thank you in advance